# running a command on pi boot after IP is assigned

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-jessie, port-forwarding

I am trying to run the below command to run automatically on startup

```
upnpc -a `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1` 80 5900 TCP
```

I have added this command in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` as I wanted it to run for the user pi only.

but it is not working, as I can see the port forward doesnt appear in router page virtual servers , however if I run the above command manually from the shell of pi , it works and forwarded port appears in router page.

I followed [this discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=14588) regarding where to put.

Comment: If you are running a recent version of Raspbian there is an option in raspi-config to wait for network at boot. It slows the boot time very slightly. You can use the following command to get the menu sudo raspi-config. Having said that are you sure that is why it is failing?

Comment: well strange but  I hardcoded internal ip of my server rather than greping and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a systemd service for your program and enable it via systemctl.

First, create a file `/etc/systemd/system/<name>.service` on the Pi. (Be sure to replace `<name>` with a actual service name.)

`sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/<name>.service`

Write in this file with your favorite text editor (nano, etc):

```
[Unit]
Description=blah service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=pi
ExecStart=yourcommand


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Replace *yourcommand* with the command you want to run. Then save the file and close the text editor.

Next, reload the daemon to make systemd recognize your service:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Then, we can make it run on boot now:

`sudo systemctl enable <name>`

(Again, make sure to replace `<name>` with the name of your service.)

Enjoy your start-on-boot command!

EDIT: didn't realize this post was that old actually. but anyways, either mark a answer as correct or state your solution in a answer and mark that so it doesn't show up on the front page

Comment: Systemd is loads better than init.rc scripts. Thanks for this guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the command as pi do su -l pi -c "put command inside quotation marks" instead of just doing it normally. So, for example, su -l pi -c "upnpc -a `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1` 80 5900 TCP".

Comment: where will this go ?